# Login a User in laravel application after API endpoint authentication

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I am working on this application where i created an API to do the business logic and using Laravel as the core part of my application that calls the API endpoints for resources.

Authentication is been done by the API which only returns a JSON resource. I am a bit confused as to what is the best way to log a user into my laravel application after successful authentication from the API.

```
//
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $data = [
      'username' => $request->username,
      'password' => $request->password,
    ];

    $data = Json_encode($data, TRUE);

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Content-Type: application/json"
    ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $response = Json_decode($response);
    // var_dump($response);
    if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {

      if ($response->status === 'failed') {

          if ($response->message === "Incorrect login details") {

              return redirect()->back()->with('error' , $response->message);

          }elseif ($response->message === "User's account has not been activated") {

              return view('activation', ['email' => $response->data]);

          }

      }elseif ($response->status === 'success' && $response->message === "Ok") {

          $user = $response->data;

          Auth::login($user , true);

          return view('dashboard', ['user' => $user]);

      }

    }
```

After getting the required response from the API, intend logging the user straight into the application. 
What is the best way for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have same database to connect with on the user. you can just simply call

```
Auth::loginUsingId($id);
```

this will automatically log in user with that id.